# joomla can't set the main page in the menu

Tags: php, joomla

I'am trying to set one of the items of Mainmenu to main page, but I gen an error that:

```
at least one the items must be set as main
```

but I've already got one, i just want to change it to other, is that a bug?

Comment: what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: ok and are you using multiple languages on your site? Have you ensured you're running the latest version of Joomla 2.5 >>> 2.5.16

Comment: yes, so i'need to update?

Comment: 2.5.16 is the latest version of the 2.5 series. If you don't already have it, then I suggest you upgrade to it as **if** this **is** a bug, then id could possibly fix it. Have a read of [this](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2391457), it might help you

Comment: please answer to this my question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117846/joomla-component-how-to-avoid-refilling-the-password-field?noredirect=1#comment29979143_20117846

Comment: I've updated to 25.16, but still have that bug!

Comment: are you using multiple languages on your site? Go to the link I provided you with in my last comment#